# Local intranet zone sites opening in IE instead of Edge

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer-11

In our enterprise Windows environment, we have started using Microsofts cloud offerings. One problem we have encountered is that login.microsoftonline.com always switches from Edge to IE during login.

EnterpriseMode is enabled in the environment, however, login.microsoftonline.com is not in the EnterpriseMode sites list. When sites are opened in EnterpriseMode we can see it in the tools menu of IE, but this is not the case with login.microsoftonline.com.

*.microsoftonline.com is, however, in the local intranet zone.

Is there a GPO that makes local intranet zone behave like EnterpriseMode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a GPO settings called: "[Send all intranet sites to Internet Explorer 11](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/deploy/group-policies/interoperability-enterprise-guidance-gp#send-all-intranet-sites-to-internet-explorer-11)"

You can find this GPO Under Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Microsoft Edge.